# How to block airflow under an interior door over carpet

Tags: insulation, door-frame

I have an air conditioned bedroom. I'd like to prevent heat from entering thru the door. I got door seals for the sides the top of the door, but I can't figure out a good solution for the bottom of the door.

The door is above carpet, so I'm not sure if a vinyl door bottom intended for an outside-facing door is appropriate.

I also saw some "draft stoppers" that go on the bottom of the door, but they are visually conspicuous and have mixed reviews.

Any suggestions? Please remember that this is an indoor door over a carpeted floor.

The gap is quite big:
[image]

Comment: I guess the room has a window mounted A/C unit and not a house-wide system?

Comment: Correct. The rest of the house is hot. The AC works extra hard to counter the rapid stream of hot air seeping thru the door.

Comment: You say the draft stoppers (which seem like a good choice to me) are "visually conspicuous".  Is being attractive a main goal, or do you want it to be somewhat hidden?

Comment: Where is the air going once it enters the bedroom? The "rapid stream" must have an exit according to the laws of the universe. Why is there such negative pressure in a bedroom?

Comment: @JPhi1618, insulation is my main goal. Ideally the contraption would be hidden, but I'll settle for anything that is easy on the eyes. I haven't seen any draft stoppers that satisfy this need.

Comment: @isherwood i suspect that the culprit is the ceiling vents. Hot air rises thru the house and escapes there perhaps. Am I supposed to shut these during summer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google "bottom mount door sweep" for any number of inconspicuous options. It appears that your gap is roughly 3/4", which should be fairly easy to fill.

Really, though, I'd investigate why an interior door has so much airflow around it. A window a/c unit should have no trouble keeping up in a single bedroom. You should be able to see your breath.

Comment: I have updated my post with a picture of the gap. I looked at the door sweeps that you mentioned. I'm not sure if they will work well above carpet - will they?

Comment: Why not? Vinyl flaps and nylon brushes, properly sized, will skim the carpet just fine, assuming a flat floor.

Comment: Concerning your other point - "investigate why an interior door has so much airflow". I suspect that this is because of the ceiling vents. I suspect that hot air thru the house rises up and makes its way thru the ceiling vents. Are these supposed to be shut in summer time?

Comment: If they're truly vents (to the outdoors), and not return air ducts, then I'd say they should be open in summer and closed in winter. I can't really be sure, though.

Comment: They also make door sweeps that snap down when the door finishes closing.

Comment: I thought of those, but they're pretty cumbersome and clunky for a bedroom.

Comment: @isherwood, from what you describe, I'm guessing I'm getting my terminology confused. I'm talking about a vent in the ceiling from which hot air comes into the room (if the furnace is on). Should I close this vent when running the AC? Is that why I have a big draft?

Comment: Doesn't your a/c arrive via the same vent? Where I am it's the same system.

Comment: @isherwood I don't have central AC. I have a portable unit. I only have central heating.

Comment: Oh, right. Wasn't thinking there. Yes, you may want to close them unless you run the fan for fresh air, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A 'door sock' will do the trick. A tight cold room can also introduce an abundance of condensation development inside the wall cavity leading to mold growth.

Answer (score 0):

Look for something called an automatic door sweep. These are devices that have a spring loaded sweep which raises when the door is opened. When the door is closed a cam is activated which drops the sweep.